# does bing map control for WP7 provide a feature of "tracking shape manually"?

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps, arcgis, esri

what I mean is something like this:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/WindowsPhone/samples/start.htm

go to that ESRI sample and choose "Graphics" and then choose "Add interactively".
In that sample, you can use mouse(if it's a phone, I suppose we can use fingers) to draw polygons, lines to the top of the map.

does the bing map control for WP7 provide something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the WP7 control is the same as the normal Silverlight control, you can add `shapes` to your Bing Map by adding [MapPolygons()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681899.aspx). If not, you can still add [polygons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polygon%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [polylines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polyline%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (as well as other [shapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189073%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)) via [Silverlight](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/SilverlightPolyLine12102008000658AM/SilverlightPolyLine.aspx) and display it on top.

Comment: thanks, i've notice that we can create geometries and add them to bing map. What I was asking is that is there any built-in functionality like the ESRI sample shows in bing map control.

Comment: so the question should be: can i create a polygon with out writing code to deal with tapping events?

Comment: No, I haven't seen that functionality. AFAIK, you'll have to handle tapping events manually. Happy to be corrected by someone though :)